# Do miscellaneous items take up inventory space?

Tags: dead-island

I was just wondering if all the items you collect over time take up space in your inventory making it so you can't have as many weapons, med kits and items of importance? I just sold a lot of my things, I had a crazy amount of stuff, can you keep collecting with no penalties, i.e. space issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only things that take up space in your inventory are usable items: weapons, health kits, alcohol etc.

Things like wire, algae, batteries (the miscellaneous items) do NOT take up space.

You will find as you play through the game that a lot of the weapon mods tend to appear after Act 1 and usually require more than 1 of an item (eg. Batteries x2). Keep every miscellaneous thing you loot. Miscellaneous items that show up in green (like the LP3400 battery) are used in later level mods (like ones found in Act 3).

Comment: Cheers Albort! :)

Comment: @Sarah If someone's answered your question to your satisfaction, please "Accept" it by clicking the checkmark in the upper left. Thanks! :)

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes I know how it works, I'm waiting for more answers before i make a decison.

Comment: @Sarah I haven't posted an answer because Albort's answer is correct.  I wouldn't have anything more to say than this answer has, so another answer wouldn't make sense.